# Clerification needed re: INSERT base64 to BLOB in mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, canvas

I am collecting a signature on an agreement form with a canvas element. Before the form is submitted the canvas element is converted to a base64 string that is then stored in a HIDDEN form field.

When the base64 string hits the PHP page that is processing and INSERT-ing the form elements into my database it looks like the following:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ......RgABAQAAS
```

I have tried many different combos of ENCODE and DECODE... ESCAPE_STRING ... GET FILE CONTENTS... to get this base64 string saved into my database, but the data never makes it to the database.

My PHP that is INSERT-ing this form into my database currently looks like:

```
<?php 
include ('header.php');
include ('connect.php');
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO deposit (type, amount, created, agreement, signature, project_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssbs", $type, $amount, $created, $agreement, $signature, $project_id);
// set parameters
$created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$amount = htmlspecialchars($_POST['amount']);
$type = htmlspecialchars($_POST['type']);
$agreement = $_POST['agreement'];


$hidden_data = $_POST['hidden_data'];
$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string ($hidden_data);
$signature = base64_decode($escaped);


$project_id = $_POST['project_id'];
// execute 
$stmt->execute();
$deposit_id = ($stmt->insert_id);
echo "$amount - created successfully";
$stmt->close();
?>
<form action="project.php" method="post">
    <div class="wrapper">   
        <input name="project_id" value="<?php echo $project_id; ?>" type="hidden">
        <input type="submit" value="Go back to project">
    </div>  
</form>
<?php 
include ('disconnect.php');
include ('footer.php');
?>
```

If I am understanding the process correctly,  I need to:

1) strip the "data:image/jpeg;base64," from the beginning of the string

2) convert or decode or encode the remaining data

3) save the data to the BLOB with an INSERT

Much of what I have found for information on this process looks so much different from how my code here is set up that I am not understanding how to re-organize it to fit within what I have here. Can someone please clarify for me how this process works within the type of CODE structure I am using here?

I have do have another place in this app that collects an image from a camera, stores it in a file and is handled using $_FILE instead of $_POST. This process works, the image is stored in the database BLOB and I am able to GET the info later for display. That code looks like:

```
$data = $conn->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
```

I tried just changing $_FILES to $_POST but that just broke everything.

Thank you in advance for your time.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the form that collects the data used here:

```
<?php 
include ('header.php');
include ('legal_deposit_agreement_display.php');
?>
<form action="legal_deposit_agreement_create.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" name="form">

    <input name="hidden_data" id='hidden_data' type="hidden"/>
    <input name="project_id" value="<?php echo $project_id; ?>" type="hidden">

    <h1>Deposit</h1>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <label>Ammount of Deposit</label><br>
        <input name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" placeholder="Enter Ammount of deposit here" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">   
        <label>Payment Type</label><br>
        <select name="type" tabindex="3">
            <option value="Cash/Credit"<?php if ($type == 'Cash/Credit') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Cash/Credit</option>
            <option value="Gift Certificate"<?php if ($type == 'Gift Certificate') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>Gift Certificate</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <label>Deposit Agreement</label><br>
        <textarea id="agreement" name="agreement" style="overflow:hidden" TextMode="MultiLine" onkeyup="setHeight('textBox1');" onkeydown="setHeight('textBox1');" tabindex="4" value="<?php include 'text/depositAgreement.txt';?>"><?php include 'text/depositAgreement.txt';?></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setHeight(fieldId){
                document.getElementById(fieldId).style.height = document.getElementById(fieldId).scrollHeight+'px';
            }
            setHeight('agreement');
        </script>
    </div>

    <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
        <div class="signature-pad--body">
          <canvas id="canvas" name="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="signature-pad--footer">
          <div class="description">Sign above</div>

          <div class="signature-pad--actions">
            <div>
              <button type="button" class="button clear" data-action="clear">Clear</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/signature_pad.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="button" onclick="convert()" value="I AGREE TO ALL OF THE TERMS DESCRIBED ABOVE">
    </div>

</form>

<script>
    function convert() {
        document.getElementById('hidden_data').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
        document.forms["form"].submit();
    };
</script>

<?php include ('footer.php');?>
```

Comment: You say that: *"That code looks like: `$data = $conn->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));`"* - yet this line of code `$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string ($hidden_data);`  failed.  So, why didn't you pass the connnection to it also? If that's all this is, there's a duplicate for it. However, there's no input of that name.

Comment: so, where's the form with the file input then? This question's unclear.

Comment: in the code that I used to send the photo to the database the $conn is only called that one time. In the code that I am using to send this form it is called earlier in the code so I was not sure if I needed to call it a second time. When I tried to keep the $conn in there the code broke and nothing worked at all. Currently the code I am using INSERTs everything except the BLOB.

Comment: I will add the form code for the input page in an edit.

Comment: you have 2 different files and 2 different forms. If you're going to want to use both, use sessions.

Comment: I posted something below. If that doesn't satisfy the question, I'll delete it; just say the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files / `$_FILES` require a valid enctype in `<form>`, being `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and that isn't part of what you posted.

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

There should be an input type of `file` in there and using the named attribute for it, then passing that variable assigned to the `$_FILES` superglobal. You can then use the `b` as you did in your `bind_param()`.

This line doesn't contain the file input for it in your post:

```
$data = $conn->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
```

If you want to upload a BLOB to your database, then use what I posted here and read the manual on handling files.

This line failed because you didn't pass the connection argument for it:

```
$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string ($hidden_data);
```

which should read as:

```
$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $hidden_data);
```

Comment: In this case I am not using  $_FILES because the base64 string is generated by JS and placed into a hidden text field before the form is submitted. I did add the $conn into my current code as you described, but still no data is stored in the database.

Comment: @inkslinger use php's error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` on the queries, see what that produces.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to use the error reporting now. It may take me some time to figure out how to use it correctly. I will post results as soon as I figure it out. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @inkslinger `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` is how to check for errors with php and what I posted for the query above in another comment.

Comment: okay, I added: ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); above my php code. How do I use the mysqli_error($conn) part correctly? Do I just add that to my current PHP at the end or do I have to Echo something so it displays? I apologize for my unfamiliarity with all of this. I am teaching myself as I go.

Comment: @inkslinger change your `$stmt->execute();` to `if(!$stmt->execute()){
 
 echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
 
}`

Comment: When I added error checking as you described here, no errors were displayed. Everything went into the database except the BLOB.

Comment: @inkslinger your first code/form doesn't contain any file inputs or the enctype, that is why it's not going in. You only have that in another body of code. Basically, a case of "the left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing".

Comment: I see, so I can not use the hidden form text field "hidden_data" to pass the base64 string to a BLOB in a $_POST. It has to be a $_FILES?

Comment: @inkslinger that's correct. If you want to handle files and upload as a BLOB, it needs to be a file input type with an enctype, as described in the answer.

Comment: okay. thank you for the help. In your opinion, would you collect this information in two parts then? Use a form and $_POST to collect the info and then a file and $_FILES to collect just the signature?